# HTML not parsing properly on image creation in php

Tags: php, image

I have to generate a magazine, got few records with exact path of images. Sort out all records in a string and now want to create a JPG or PNG file having the output of that string.

I used this code.

```
        //set size of image
        $pic = @imagecreatetruecolor(2835, 3898);

        //setting text color
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($pic, 0, 0, 0); //black color

        //setting bg color
        $bgColor = imagecolorallocate($pic, 255,255,255); //white color
        imagefill($pic , 0,0 , $bgColor);

        //setting text with text color
        imagestring($pic, 1, 5, 5,  $output, $text_color);

        //generating JPG
        Imagepng($pic,$path."01.jpg");

        //clearing image cache
        ImageDestroy($pic);
```

Here $output is the string name.

It shows the html code of output values while the included images and backgrounds of divs are not appearing.

Can any one help me out in this regard.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set a header if you want to display the image or make it downloadable

set

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required 
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"image.jpg;" ); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

right before displaying the image

from php.net

Comment: At least, the content-type-header is needed. Then in your html do the normal `img`-implementation like: `<img src="my_image.php" alt="Image" />`

Comment: when I pasted these header. I get an error with blank page. 

There is an error in this file.

...

Comment: try using only `header("Content-Type: image/png");` and please show the error message you got

Answer (score 0):

imagestring() doesn't parse HTML

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

The closest thing I can imagine to what you want would be to use the HTML2PDF library to generate a PDF and then use a PDF2TIFF tool to rasterize it, then convert the TIFF to whatever image format you want to actually output it as.

Or maybe you could use phpGTK / GTKWebKit to directly rasterize it.  Basically you'd be writing a small browser in PHP.

Comment: thanks for your support, but still no success. 

because html page is generating dynamically and i want to add images in html div backgrounds. which are not embbeding

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/
This will do what you need.  Look at the wkhtmltopng package.  You can generate HTML as a temp file, run this and it will produce an image output for you.